# Eval("groovy template") in play 1 framework

Tags: javascript, groovy, playframework

I'm trying to append groovy template to DOM at specific point in time as such:

```
function onload(){
     globalEval();
}
var globalEval = function globalEval() {
    var src = "#{all-tags /};"
    if (window.execScript) {
        window.execScript(src);
        return;
    }
    var fn = function() {
        window.eval.call(window,src);
    };
    fn();
}
```

But the template gets rendered immediately, and that's not what is intended.How to attach groovy template to DOM only when necessary?

Comment: I'm guessing the groovy template is in the src variable. But that's not groovy code. Do you have a more complete example?